# Need a sparse matrix library

Tags: matrix, sparse-matrix, blas

Is there a sparse matrix library that copies the functionality of dense BLAS?

I'd want at least:

1. efficient SYR and SYRK (rank-k update) with sparse input (and possibly dense output),
2. option for sparse symmetric storage,
3. DOT, NRM2, transpose and other standard goodies.

The naming and API doesn't need to be BLAS-centric though, as long as it does the job. C or Fortran preferred, but C++ is also ok.

I looked at [MKL](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-mkl/), [scipy.sparse](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/sparse.html), [uBLAS](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/numeric/ublas/doc/index.htm) and [Eigen3](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page), but they either didn't support what I need or I couldn't figure out whether they do.

Comment: I have found a lot of joy with sparse support in Matlab and R.  For R, look @ these packages: Matrix, sparseM, and spam.  There are others, but I am away from my computer.

Answer (score 2):

I'm sorry to disappoint, but, as far as I can tell, I am afraid the answer is no.  I've worked extensively with sparse data and have not found any deep libraries (i.e. BLAS-level) for sparse matrix manipulations.  At a higher level than BLAS, there is extensive support in Matlab, R, Python, and other languages.

From what I've seen, this arises because of the variations in the types of sparse matrices (scattered, symmetric, banded or tridiagonal, block diagonal), their contents (binary, integer, real), and their mathematical properties (e.g. positive definite - not guaranteed, full rank - not common), etc. tends to complicate the optimizations.

Instead, I tend to write my own code for processing sparse matrices, re-using what I can for the storage and simple computations like multiplication.

In time, a good low-level library will arise, but I've not yet seen it.

Answer (score 0):

There are sparse blas implementations

http://software.intel.com/sites/products/documentation/hpc/compilerpro/en-us/cpp/win/mkl/refman/bla/bla_SBLAS2-3.html